# Check Ruby syntax programmatically

Tags: ruby, parsing

How can I check if Ruby code is parsable, without executing it?

Basically, I want the functionality of `ruby -c code.rb`, without actually writing to a temporary file. Note that there is the problem of properly escaping the code if one is to use `ruby -ce 'some_ruby_code'`.

Ideally, there should be something in the standard lib, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Felix awesome, I will close this question as duplicate when I go home. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`ruby -c` can read from standard input, like in `cat code.rb | ruby -c`.

Interactively you can `ruby -c`, type in text and press Ctrl+D to signalize end-of-file.

Examples are for Linux/Unix, no idea how this would work in Windows.

Comment: That is a possible workaround. However, I would prefer if I could stay in ruby. Piping is better than reading/writing files, but still has its issues. Ideally, I don't want to call external commands at all.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate, then :)